# Entity Framework Core: Unable to run migration script on production server, The maximum key length for a clustered index is 900 bytes

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, plesk, entity-framework-core-3.1

I'm trying to deploy my ASP.NET Core website on a production server, hosted with Plesk. I have 2 projects in my solution: 1 containing my `DbContext`, 1 containing my web project.

I generated migrations for my `DbContext`:

```
dotnet ef migrations add AddIdentity --project ..\MyProject.Data
```

Then I generated a production migration script as mentioned in the docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet#dotnet-ef-migrations-script)

```
dotnet ef migrations script --idempotent --output "MigrationScripts\AddIdentity.sql" --context MyDbContext --project ..\MyProject.Data
```

Then I navigated to the SQL utility on my production server (MyLittleAdmin) and pasted the generated SQL script in it. This succeeds but I get the following error:

> Warning! The maximum key length for a clustered index is 900 bytes. The index 'PK_AspNetUserLogins' has maximum length of 1800 bytes. For some combination of large values, the insert/update operation will fail.
>
> Warning! The maximum key length for a clustered index is 900 bytes. The index 'PK_AspNetUserTokens' has maximum length of 1804 bytes. For some combination of large values, the insert/update operation will fail.

If ignoring this error, I would probably get in trouble later on with queries failing for "no apparent reason" (this reason).

My code is very straightforward:

```
internal class MintPlayerContext : IdentityDbContext<User, Role, int>
{
    private readonly IConfiguration configuration;
    public MintPlayerContext(IConfiguration configuration) : base()
    {
        this.configuration = configuration;
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("MintPlayer"), options => options.MigrationsAssembly("MintPlayer.Data"));
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}

internal class User : IdentityUser<int>
{
    public string PictureUrl { get; set; }
}

internal class Role : IdentityRole<int>
{
}
```

I also tried using Guid's (I want to use Guids eventually) but even with int's MyLittleAdmin complaints about the Key being too long.
I already checked on Google but this only gives diagnostic articles and does not really provide a solution.

Right now this is the AspNetUsers section of the migration:

```
CREATE TABLE [AspNetUsers] (
    [Id] int NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [UserName] nvarchar(256) NULL,
    [NormalizedUserName] nvarchar(256) NULL,
    [Email] nvarchar(256) NULL,
    [NormalizedEmail] nvarchar(256) NULL,
    [EmailConfirmed] bit NOT NULL,
    [PasswordHash] nvarchar(max) NULL,
    [SecurityStamp] nvarchar(max) NULL,
    [ConcurrencyStamp] nvarchar(max) NULL,
    [PhoneNumber] nvarchar(max) NULL,
    [PhoneNumberConfirmed] bit NOT NULL,
    [TwoFactorEnabled] bit NOT NULL,
    [LockoutEnd] datetimeoffset NULL,
    [LockoutEnabled] bit NOT NULL,
    [AccessFailedCount] int NOT NULL,
    [PictureUrl] nvarchar(max) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_AspNetUsers] PRIMARY KEY ([Id])
);
```

What can I do to solve this?

**Edit:**

I tried modifying my DbContext configuration to force the Key to be only the Id:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasKey(u => u.Id);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Role>().HasKey(r => r.Id);
}
```

This seems to affect the migration indeed:

```
[Id] int NOT NULL IDENTITY,
```

Instead of:

```
[Id] uniqueidentifier NOT NULL,
```

But it still gives the same error

**Edit: Adding the AspNetUserLogins, AspNetUserRoles, stripped the if's**

```
CREATE TABLE [AspNetUserLogins] (
    [LoginProvider] nvarchar(450) NOT NULL,
    [ProviderKey] nvarchar(450) NOT NULL,
    [ProviderDisplayName] nvarchar(max) NULL,
    [UserId] int NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_AspNetUserLogins] PRIMARY KEY ([LoginProvider], [ProviderKey]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_AspNetUserLogins_AspNetUsers_UserId] FOREIGN KEY ([UserId]) REFERENCES [AspNetUsers] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE [AspNetUserTokens] (
    [UserId] int NOT NULL,
    [LoginProvider] nvarchar(450) NOT NULL,
    [Name] nvarchar(450) NOT NULL,
    [Value] nvarchar(max) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_AspNetUserTokens] PRIMARY KEY ([UserId], [LoginProvider], [Name]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_AspNetUserTokens_AspNetUsers_UserId] FOREIGN KEY ([UserId]) REFERENCES [AspNetUsers] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Comment: You've almost certainly still got a `string` somewhere as a primary key (since this will be used as the default clustered index by EF / SQL Server). Have a look for something like this : `AspNetUserLogin : IdentityUserLogin<string>`

Comment: I updated my question by adding a piece of the generated migration script. I can see that the Primary key exists of only the Id (either an int or uniqueidentifier -> Guid)

Comment: The warning is being reported on `AspNetUserLogins` and  `AspNetUserTokens` - you're not showing the definitions of those classes. I'm sure there's a string in there.

Comment: You're right. Good point. I'll post these SQL scripts.

Comment: So AspNetUserLogins.LoginProvider, AspNetUserLogins.ProviderKey, AspNetUserTokens.LoginProvider and AspNetUserTokens.ProviderName are strings and can possibly be too long.

Comment: Yeah, `nvarchar(450)` already potentially takes up 900 bytes. It's a warning only - suggest you build your system with the external OAuth providers that you need (Facebook, Google, etc) and then check to see what the actual length of the strings really is and then reducing the widths. You could also consider dropping the unicode, i.e. make the columns `VARCHAR` if you don't find any non ASCII chars in these strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone, It was spot-on.
Thanks to all of your suggestions I managed to get it working.

Since I'm using Code-first, I can't just modify my generated migrations.
So this is what I've done:

```
internal class MintPlayerContext : IdentityDbContext<User, Role, int>
{
    // dotnet ef migrations add AddIdentity --project ..\MyProject.Data
    // dotnet ef database update --project ..\MyProject.Data
    // (only looks at your appsettings.json file, not your appsettings.*.json, so for local development)

    // To generate production migrations
    // dotnet ef migrations script --idempotent --output "MigrationScripts\AddIdentity.sql" --context MyDbContext --project ..\MyProject.Data

    private readonly IConfiguration configuration;
    public MintPlayerContext(IConfiguration configuration) : base()
    {
        this.configuration = configuration;
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("MyProject"), options => options.MigrationsAssembly("MyProject.Data"));
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserLogin<int>>()
            .Property(ut => ut.LoginProvider)
            .HasMaxLength(50);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserLogin<int>>()
            .Property(ut => ut.ProviderKey)
            .HasMaxLength(200);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserToken<int>>()
            .Property(ut => ut.LoginProvider)
            .HasMaxLength(50);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserToken<int>>()
            .Property(ut => ut.Name)
            .HasMaxLength(50);
    }
}
```

I will be using Guid's in order to not make UserIds guess-able.

Comment: I just tried this but i got the following error
System.InvalidOperationException: The entity type 'IdentityUserLogin<int>' requires a primary key to be defined. If you intended to use a keyless entity type call 'HasNoKey()'.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelValidator.ValidateNonNullPrimaryKeys(IModel model, IDiagnosticsLogger`1 logger)
 
How did u get around this ?

Comment: I did not encounter this problem. https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer. What version of identity are you using, cause this sounds like a bug...

Answer (score 3):

You can try changing it to:

```
CREATE TABLE [AspNetUserTokens] (
    [UserId] int NOT NULL,
    [LoginProvider] nvarchar(150) NOT NULL,
    [Name] nvarchar(150) NOT NULL,
    [Value] nvarchar(150) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_AspNetUserTokens] PRIMARY KEY ([UserId], [LoginProvider], [Name]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_AspNetUserTokens_AspNetUsers_UserId] FOREIGN KEY ([UserId]) REFERENCES [AspNetUsers] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

I think Name cant contain more than 150 characters. I mean its just a Name.

Total length of all columns need to be < than 900.

```
ALTER TABLE sampleTable ALTER COLUMN column1 VARCHAR (400) NULL;
ALTER TABLE sampleTable ALTER COLUMN column2 VARCHAR (200) NULL;
ALTER TABLE sampleTable ALTER COLUMN column3 VARCHAR (200) NULL;
```

As per comments, you should try external Oauth provides and come up with a reasonable number.

also, storage size of nvarchar is *2. 450 * 2 will trigger the error. you can try reducing it.

Comment: The posted SQL scripts are generated by EntityFrameworkCore. I'm using Code-First approach. Good lead though

Comment: The field only contains "Facebook", "Twitter", "Google", "Microsoft" or other external login providers so 50 should be more than long enough for that

Answer (score 1):

`AspNetUserLogins` and `AspNetUserTokens` need a shorter key defined. I'm assuming that no key was defined in the model, so all columns were added to the key. Perhaps including some large string columns.